# SQLServer(MSSQL) full text search index to postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have already created the full text search index in MS SQL Server.

Below is the query which I have written. I am new to Postgres so, I am trying to recreate the same thing in Postgres.

So, how can I create the same thing in postgres.

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].['example_tab'] test1,test2... KEY INDEX unique_index
          WITH STOPLIST = SYSTEM
```

Comment: @jarlh yeah mssql, now i have updated. Thank you!

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-tables.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full text search is nothing normed by a standard, so you can expect that it works differently in different database systems.

To speed up a full text search query like

```
SELECT * FROM atab
WHERE to_tsvector('english', textcol) @@ to_tsquery('english', 'search string');
```

you would create this index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON atab USING gin (to_tsvector('english', textcol));
```

Comment: how to create index for multiple columns like sql server

Comment: You can use the concatenation operator `||` on `tsvectors` and index the result.