# How to create postgres full text search index on multiple column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm migrating from sql server to postgres. IN sql server I have created the index like this:

```
 CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [testdb].[dbo].['table'] (test1,test2...) KEY INDEX unique_index
              WITH STOPLIST = SYSTEM
```

How can I created the same thing in postgres, if I'm trying to create for multiple column like this it is giving error:

```
CREATE INDEX ON [testdb].[dbo].['table'] USING gin (to_tsvector('english', test1)||to_tsvector('english',test2)||to_tsvector('english', test3));
```

Error:

**ERROR: function to_tsvector(unknown, character varying, character varying) does not exist**

Answer (score 2):

In Postgres, the `to_tsvector` function only accepts a single column as input.  But this does not mean that we cannot do a full text search using multiple columns.  For instance, assuming you wanted to query using `test1` and `test2`, rank the results, and then retrieve the top 10 matches, you could use this query:

```sql
SELECT *,
    ts_rank(
        to_tsvector('english', test1) || to_tsvector('english', test2),
        to_tsquery('english', 'your search term here')
    ) AS rnk
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    to_tsvector('english', test1) || to_tsvector('english', test2) @@
    to_tsquery('english', 'your search term here')
ORDER BY
    rnk DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: thank you, how we can create index for multiple columns.

Comment: @ashok You don't...you use a workaround, such as the one my answer suggests.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66746383/sqlservermssql-full-text-search-index-to-postgres in this question, using || symbol we can create index has been mentioned, is it possible?

Comment: sorry I have updated te question, please can you check.